# what will happen if I execute a call GMP and provide a small gas that was insufficient ? what if I did not provide more gas to complete execution?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, evm, axelar

what will happen if I executed a GMP call and provided a small gas that was insufficient ? what if I did not provide more gas to complete execution in the UI or programmatically ?

```
 GAS_RECEIVER.payNativeGasForContractCall{value: msg.value}(address(this), destinationChain, destContract, payload, msg.sender
        );
```

and then execute the Call , with parameter that i specify

```
   AXELAR_GATEWAY.callContract(destinationChain, destContract, payload);
```

the question here is :
will the call revert if i did not provide sufficient amount of gas ? and what is the security consideration in this case if i need to be informed onchain if the call does not get executed due to insufficient amount of gas ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes so the call will not go through. On the Axelarscan block explorer however you can see that there is the option to manually top off the insufficient transaction with extra gas so that the transaction goes through. Here is an example of a tx that has inssuficient funds and you can see the option to top off the extra gas
https://testnet.axelarscan.io/gmp/0x88062ec783acf7eadef8b3ca0be72289e3ea8d1cc0a6ac94b31c3cce141c8c99:1

As a rule of thumb I always prefer to pay extra gas because any extra funds will automatically be refunded to you.
Hope this helps!